# What the fastest way to get filtered attribute members in amo?

Tags: .net, ssas, olap

My aim is to get filtered member list including its properties from specific hierarchy. It's critical because of huge hierarchy.

I found two slow way:

1. MDX: it doesn't support **like** function.
2. $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEMBERS: slow and no **like** function either.
3. Amo: ?? Couldn't find a way.

What the way EXCEL, BIDS or any other viewer handles that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer simply by debugging the action in SQL Server Profiler, I was sure there was some function within AMO library. It uses MDX query, i.e.:

```
SELECT SUBSET( FILTER( ADDCALCULATEDMEMBERS( [Client].[Code].[All clients].CHILDREN ), ( INSTR( [Client].[Code].CurrentMember.Name, "999" ) > 0 ) ), 0, 1001 ) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_NAME, MEMBER_TYPE ON 0, {} ON 1 FROM [MyCube]
```